# Ruby script that fails as a cron job

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, shell, cron

I have a ruby script which i want to run as cron job.It runs perfectly fine when i run through command prompt on a linux machine. But when i run that same script using a cron job it fails.

I get following error with string encoding. Not sure why it only complains when i am running as a cron job. I have also set my shell to /bin/bash in crontab, which is same shell as my command prompt.

The error i get is as below. this happens on a split command.

```
split.encode('utf-8).split(some_str)
```

Below is the only ruby specific error, rest is an application stack, so i have omitted it.(adding it based on user request)

> in `encode': "\xE2" on US-ASCII (Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError)
>   from ruby_file.rb:172:in`block (2 levels) in analyze_logs'
>       from ruby_file.rb:170:in `each'
>       from ruby_file.rb:170:in`block in analyze_logs'
>       from ruby_file.rb:169:in `open'
>       from ruby_file.rb:169:in`analyze_logs'
>       from ruby_file.rb:416:in `run'
>       from ruby_file.rb:479:in`'

Answer (score 1):

Use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem and it will take care of all the issues related to cronjobs

```
every 6.minutes do
  rake "your_app:rake_task_name"
end
```

Comment: before I can answer that you need to provide more info on your error and some code as well.

Comment: i have added the error stack, but its very application specific. nor is there any code. its the split command that is crashing, i have already mentioned that in the question :). thanks

Comment: Can you try to set default encoding to UTF-8 and what happens like **Encoding.default_external = "utf-8"**

Comment: set default encoding where? in the shell?

Comment: In your ruby script file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the locale when run under cron is different and is causing character encoding issues.

See: http://chrisneedham.com/posts/2014/06/21/ruby-cron-utf8.html